# Refresh ETag of a resource in Java

Tags: java, amazon-s3, etag, spark-java

I have an API that integrates with S3 in order to upload/download resources.

I can successfully retrieve and cache the etags of each resource.

They are stored as an HashMap where the key is the resource's ID (a UUID to be precise), and the value is the ETag return from Amazon S3.

As an example, I have a logo for one of my entities where users can update it whenever they deem fit.

In my mind, refreshing the etag cache should occur in the PUT request by simply updating the entry in my HashMap

Would that be the proper way to do it in Java?

I run this snippet of code at the beginning of each GET request.

```
private void validateETag(UUID id, Request rq, Response rs) {

    String eTag = rq.headers("If-None-Match");
    String cachedETag = etagCache.get(id);
    if (eTag != null && cachedETag != null && eTag.equals(cachedETag)) {
        rs.header("Cache-Control", "max-age=60");
        rs.header(ETAG_KEY, eTag);
        halt(304);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can update your cached ETag ID together with the cache object itself. Since you have to deal with missing local cache objects it is not so important if you do it before or after creating the cache object, but I guess after produces less fetches.

Comment: so I am correct in thinking the best place to do is is the PUT request for the resource?

Comment: I was talking about the local cache, I.e. where you generate the temp file. It depends a bit on who updates the S3 and who downloads it. If you push the data you can generate a new cache entry put it and then update your local etag. Bt in all cases you have races.